# Android:How to delete listitem after a specific time interval of inactivity?

Tags: java, android

I have a list view which is dynamically updated.I also have `listView.setOnItemClickListener` and other details activity opens which gives more details.In the details activity I have 12 buttons.I have a requirement that I have not tried/implemented before.If any of the 12 buttons are not clicked in a month that item of the list view should be deleted.

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                //handled intent to open details activity

            }
        });
```

Details Activity:

```
 Button btnJan,btnFeb,btnMarch,btnApril,btnMay,btnJune,btnJuly,btnAugust,btnSept,btnOct,btnNov,btnDec;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        btnJan=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnJan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //handle data
            }
        });
        //similar 11 buttons exaclty same
```

Can anyone guide how can I achieve this??I did'nt find anything related to this on SO either.Thanks

Comment: store the last clicked date - have a scheduler check this value

Comment: @ScaryWombat Any documentation..useful links?.thanks

Comment: try doing some research for yourself like search for *java schedule task*

Comment: create a db and store the clicked date for every button and check that time with current time every time you open your app and if it exceeds one month delete that entry from your listview

Comment: @sumit It was the first thing i n  my mind..but my app is supposed to work offline

Comment: so whats the problem with that you can store data locally using Sqlite DB